# Setting axes on seaborn relplot/scatterplot subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I've been struggling with this for a little while, and I admit that it probably comes down to my fundamental non-understanding of seaborn and matplotlib/pyplot objects. I've not really been able to register the difference between plots, subplots, figs, axes, FacetGrids etc. I use pandas for a lot, so I'm sort of hoping to be pandas friendly.

Here is the specific code I'm wondering about. The goal is to:

1. Make a scatter plot
2. Set some axis parameters
3. Set some shading
4. THEN - add a table with some ancillary data below the plot

Ultimately, I end up with exactly what i had before I added the table (just a single scatter plot). I've had similar challenges, for example setting axes or legends, or creating a series of heat maps with a shared color/value scale.

So my two questions are -

- How can I get the table below the scatter plot?
- How am I misinterpreting the relationships/definitions between all of these objects - fig, ax, axes, plot, subplot, FacetGrid etc.

Ambitious question, I know, but not for lack of googleing/reading.

```py
def generate_plots(df_input,title,the_date,sub_grp):
    #parse out the columns i actually want from a larger df
    df_input = df_input[['Name','SubGroup','x_value','size_value','y_value','ancillary_value_1','ancillary_value_2','ancillary_value_3','ancillary_value_4','ancillary_value_5']] 

    df_scatter = df_input[df_input['SubGroup']==sub_grp]
    min_dot_size = df_input['size_value'].min() * 2
    max_dot_size = df_input['size_value'].max() * 2

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,16))
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1) #I think this segments that fig into 2 subplots and calls the first
    #add scatter plot to that first ax/subplot
    ax = sns.relplot(
        data=df_scatter,
        x="x_value",
        y="y_value",
        style = 'Name',
        hue = 'Name',
        size='size_value',
        sizes = (min_dot_size,max_dot_size),
        markers=markers_list,
        palette=sns.color_palette('bright',df_scatter['Name'].unique().shape[0]),
        zorder=3
        )
    lim_max = 1.2
    plt.xlim(0,lim_max)
    plt.ylim(0,lim_max)
    y_val_red = .8 
    y_val_yellow = .9
    x_val_red = .45
    x_val_yellow = .55
    # red for the left half (from top to bottom all the way up to x_val_red on the x axis)
    plt.axvspan(0, (x_val_red/lim_max), 0, 1/lim_max,  color='#EF9A9A', alpha=0.5)
    # red for the bottom half (from left to right all the way up to the minimum)
    plt.axvspan(0, 1, 0, (y_val_red/lim_max),  color='#EF9A9A', alpha=0.5)
    #Yellow box from the X-axis x_val_red to x_val_yellow and the y_val_red to the top
    plt.axvspan((x_val_red/lim_max), (x_val_yellow/lim_max), (y_val_red/lim_max) , 1/lim_max, color='yellow', alpha=0.5)
    #Yellow box from the X-axis phone_prod_red to phone_prod_yellow and the y_val_red to the top
    plt.axvspan((x_val_yellow/lim_max), 1, (y_val_red/lim_max) , (y_val_yellow/lim_max), color='yellow', alpha=0.5)

    plt.axhline(xmin=0,xmax=1/lim_max)
    plt.axvline(ymin=0,ymax=1/lim_max)

    plt.xticks([.2,.4,.6,.8,1],['20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'])
    plt.yticks([.2,.4,.6,.8,1],['20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'])
    plt.title(title + '\n'+topic+' ('+the_date+')')

    df_table = df_input[['Name','ancillary_value_1','ancillary_value_2','ancillary_value_3','ancillary_value_4','ancillary_value_5']].round(1).sort_values(by=['ancillary_value_1']).set_index(['Name'])
    print(df_table)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
    pd.plotting.table(ax=ax,data=df_table)
    plot_image_path = 'plot_exports/'+title+'/'+the_date+'_'+title+'_'+topic+'_scatter.png'
    plt.savefig(plot_image_path,bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close('all')
    return plot_image_path
```

[Here's a photo of the result that I get, for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L09R5.png)

Comment: One problem is that `relplot` is a ["figure level function"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) which creates a complete grid of subplots.  To control the `ax`, you need `ax = sns.scatterplot(...)` instead.